# Compiling and exporting C# solution to run on VM

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

Very naive question, for someone that just got started with VS Code and C#.

I have just finished C# code that I'd like to run on a ubuntu instance on AWS. The code runs when I hit "debug project associated with this file", but does not when I do "run code" (error: /bin/sh: 1: scriptcs: not found). So I did build, I have a "bin/Debug/net8.0" folder that created with bunch of files in it, among those a "log4" file, that when I click on it, seems that my code is running in the background.
Am I supposed to just transfer the file on my VM ? Then how can I run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Install the .Net runtime on [ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)**

2. **transfer your app**
   You'll need to transfer the entire output directory (bin/Debug/net8.0 or whichever configuration you used) to your Ubuntu instance.

> ```
> scp -r ./bin/Debug/net8.0 username@your-ubuntu-instance-ip:/path/to/destination
> ```

than you just run the application

```
dotnet MyApp.dll
```

Just change MyApp with the name of the application and make sure you are in the directory your app was moved to

hope this is clear enough